# command-line utility to record from microphone

Tags: linux, bash, audio, command-line, sox

I am looking for command-line utility that monitors the microphone, and if you start to speak, writes the file. Recording period should be adjusted.

Solution is:

```
   sox -t alsa default recording.wav silence 1 0.1 5% 1 1.0 5%
```

Comment: Please see the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  That is not the type of questions we deal with here.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/545329/blank-screen-if-kids-yell-too-much/545334#545334

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From http://dabase.com/u/record_wav/

```
arecord -vv -fdat stackoverflow.wav
```

Comment: this command writes output file constantly with silence. Тhis is not something that I need

Comment: Does your Mic work with Skype testing? Is it enabled via `alsamixer`?

Comment: Yes Mic working with skype, enabled

Comment: I tried it and it is working > arecord -vv -fdat stackoverflow.wav I think the problem is that you are not selecting microphone in the settings, you have analog input instead change that and it should work

Comment: @hendry: Did you even read the question. The asker wants something that only triggers when a sound is heard, and then records for a specific period of time.

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen lol I only noticed that this fact when I have find this solution great to me. The author failed to address what he wanted clearly in the **title**, and even Google "didn't even read the question" and led me here!