# Are there any man in the middle proxy experts here?(preferably Fiddler)

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I am not fluent in English, so I will explain using 2 searches contained in the images below with `Breaking Bad` tv series as an example ...

Search 1:

[image]

Search 2:

[image]

If  someone searches Google or any other search engine this phrase (`-torrent-download-watch`) should be automatically and invisibly added.

Are there any MITM proxy Gurus around here that can help me? If creating the script is hard, I can (please tell me if this is against the rules) hire someone.

Comment: My kids downloading off videos,if i try parental control software they will notice it.but with my method it is like cutting diamond with diamond exactly what i need( forgive my english

Comment: *"One suggestion would be to just program the kids directly. However, some people prefer the indirect route through the computer, which does provide a convenient pre-existing portal."* ([source](http://superuser.com/q/545329/194694)).

Comment: Btw, if they would notice parental control then they will notice Fiddler.

Comment: "possible duplicate of How to make Google Search look dumb?".This question is more devoted to MITM proxies and i want every other search engine to be modified(not just google).

Comment: I don't want to tell you how to raise your children, but I think you're underestimating them. Sooner or later they *will* realise something's wrong because they have friends who will tell them "works for me". In the best case your kids will ask friends to copy downloaded files to their pendrive or they will watch them together. In addition, they will probably realise that it's you who's messing with their Google results and then they will make sure you have even more parenting problems.

Comment: I got letter from the ISP,and the internet bills, oh my duck the bills are high.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/267029) we have here. We could be able to find better solutions if you asked how to block streaming and torrents to save bandwidth.

Comment: @gronostaj - Might be off-topic,but where can i hire some Fiddler experts to write a script for me?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly your post, you want to add your custom Switches to Google Search Module, and with these switches to filter specific results from specific pages without the switches getting appended to the Search String.

That actually can be done using UserScripts. A user script is a piece of JavaScript code executed on a defined by user , web page, aiming to improve User's experience on the particular Web Page.

There are many UserScript interpreters out there but the most common are.

1. [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) for Chromium Projects (Google Chrome...)
2. [GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) for FireFox Projects (FireFox,Gluon...)

Comment: I tried them,but i think fiddler is more suitable for me.As an example ,what if other family members use diffrent browers or different devices?.

Comment: You can simply create a static configuration and loading it on each of your home's browser. Messing up with raw Network Packets, and altering them, is harder than my suggestion.

Comment: Sorry,but i did not understand what you said,Can you please give me an example?

Comment: You can create a package with GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey + UserScript and auto loading them on every browser that they are not loaded.

Modifying the packets sent from your Network to the Internet its tricky and hard thing to do in order to achieve the results you want

Comment: That sounds complicated,Anyway i am thinking of using Fiddler as Transparent Proxy.For you which is less tricky and time consuming.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/800331/357436 .  I copied the script to tampermonkey and saved it,then clicked home page(google.com) typed Breaking Bad,not working.Tried it several times,Can you please tell what went wrong?